# How to extract fieldname of PdfFormField from PdfAnnotation

Tags: itext, formfield

So I create a radio group using this PdfFormField.createRadioButton() then calling the setFieldName().

However, the PdfAnnotation does not show any keys that stores the field name. I looked at the other dictionaries inside the PdfAnnotation but could not find any.

reader.getAcroFields().getFields().keySet() does list the field names of the form fields but I wish to ask if there is any way via PdfAnnotation?

I tried to put a custom PdfName inside the radio group object but it does not show up in the PdfAnnotation's dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing the concept of an annotation (link annotation, file attachment annotation, widget annotation,...) and a form field (text field, choice field, button field, signature field).

In iText 5, annotations are dealt with in a class named `PdfAnnotation`; form fields are dealt with in a class named `PdfFormField`. You are trying to do something that is specific for a `PdfFormField` using the class `PdfAnnotation`. That's wrong.

I understand the root of the confusion: every *visible* form field corresponds with *at least one* widget annotation. Most of the *visible* form fields correspond with *exactly one* widget annotation. That's why we made a design choice in iText 5 to have `PdfFormField` extends `PdfAnnotation`.

This design choice is in line with the PDF specification where it says that field dictionaries of fields that correspond with a single widget annotation may be merged into a single PDF dictionary.

In practice, you will find PDF dictionaries in a PDF that combine entries typical for a widget annotation dictionary and a field dictionary. (That also explains why there's a `getMerged()` method in iText: that method gets you the merged dictionary objects.)

I hope this already explains part of your problem. You seem to have another problem too, but I don't understand what you want to do. Please clarify using references to ISO-32000-1 so that people can understand which technical feature you are trying to implement.

Comment: Hi Bruno, thank you for the clarification. When I created checkboxes using RadioCheckField, I could not find the field name in the dictionary of the annotation but I was able to find it in the AcroFields. I believe I found what I am looking for. Thank you